# How can I make [object object] readable while parsing socket.io object

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to look my room list in socket.io.

But console return only [object Object].

My code is this.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
   console.log('rooms: '+rooms);
}
```

And my console log is

```
rooms: [object Object]
```

There is something odd about it.

I write code.

```
for (var key in rooms){
    console.log('key: '+key);
}
```

Then, console write socket.id of connected client.

such as

```
key: iFUdbwRtB5oRMcf3AAAA
```

Comment: Try parsing your key object like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(key));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this

```
console.log('rooms: '+rooms);
```

to this:

```
console.log('rooms: ', rooms);
```

Using an object in a string manipulation causes `.toString()` to get called on it and the default string conversion of an object is `[object Object]`.  Outputting the object directly with `console.log()` will show the object's actual contents and not just attempt a generic string conversion.

Comment: What a great point. Helped me not to spend some hours on tracking the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply stringify the rooms:

```
console.log('rooms: ', JSON.stringify(rooms, null, 10));
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` does not work when there are circular references and I think there might be circular references inside of `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`.  Also, if you just let `console.log()` output the object for you, then you can more easily navigate and view the results in the console window (since you can expand and collapse complicated objects).